# Pdf to XML/json using Python module

Tags: python

I am able to read the text from pdf using code:

```
import pdfx
pdf = pdfx.PDFx("1951.pdf")
metadata = pdf.get_metadata()
reference_list = pdf.get_references()
reference_dict = pdf.get_references_as_dict()
pdf.download_pdfs("D:/")
pdf.get_text()
```

But can't convert it into json:

```
pdfx -d D:/Output/ -j -o output.json pdf
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Syntax: pdfx [-h] [-d OUTPUT_DIRECTORY] [-c] [-j] [-v] [-t] [-o OUTPUT_FILE]
            [--version]
            pdf

Answer (score 8):

I was able to convert to XML using the Pdfminer Python module.

1. Download and unzip the module from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer/
2. Run on shell: python pdf2txt.py -o samples/output.xml -t xml samples/1951.pdf
3. For text    : python pdf2txt.py samples/1951.pdf

Comment: you are using pdf2txt .py, Is this file persent in pdfminer module ?

Comment: Yes pdf2txt.py comes with pdfminer module

Comment: it comes with pdfminer but located under Scripts folder of Python